# Rails 4 routes with simple_form and shallow nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-resources

```
  resources :accounts, shallow: true do
    resources :textnotes 
  end
```

Gives me

```
   account_textnotes GET    /accounts/:account_id/textnotes(.:format)     textnotes#index
                     POST   /accounts/:account_id/textnotes(.:format)     textnotes#create
new_account_textnote GET    /accounts/:account_id/textnotes/new(.:format) textnotes#new
       edit_textnote GET    /textnotes/:id/edit(.:format)                 textnotes#edit
            textnote GET    /textnotes/:id(.:format)                      textnotes#show
                     PATCH  /textnotes/:id(.:format)                      textnotes#update
                     PUT    /textnotes/:id(.:format)                      textnotes#update
```

When I try to create a new note

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/accounts/4/textnotes/new
<%= simple_form_for(@textnote) do |f| %>
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError in Textnotes#new
Showing /Users/xyz/rails_projects/crm/app/views/textnotes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `textnotes_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8204f37360>:0x007f8204be4fa0>
```

Comment: I don't know simple_form but it seems like you would need to supply both the `@textnote` and also the `@account` object to this method for it to work?

Comment: you have declared `textnote_path` not a `textnotes_path`. may the that is issue? and what is the `@textnote` object is?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add a `url` parameter to `simple_form_for` specifying `accounts_textnotes_path`?

With the shallow nesting setup you're posting to the index path of the parent resource (which I believe your routes output above shows).

If that doesn't work you could always try specifying a string path or an action.

(As always, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html may help.)

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You have to specify the parent account like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@account, @textnote]) do |f| %>
```